# Disallow users from viewing Redirected Share root?

Tags: active-directory, folder-redirection

I have user documents redirected to a share on a server. The share is \\Server1\UserDocs\%username%

I don't want the users to be able to navigate to \\Server1\UserDocs\ and view each others documents. How can I prevent this from happening?

Thanks!

Comment: ABE? - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc784710(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: You're asking for two different things. The title asks how to stop them from viewing the root. The question asks how you cans toot hem from seeing other user's documents. Which are you actually  after, as they're two very different things?

Comment: If they are able to view the root of the share which is \\server1\usersdocs (location where redirected docs go) then they are able to view all documents redirected there. Is that completely different? I don't want them to navigate to the main share where all other folders are

Comment: @EdgarCParra No, that's not true. You're mistaken. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

You use NTFS permissions on each %username% folder that are set in such a way that only the user, and possibly an administrator, can see it.

After reading your comment, you seem to be missing an important detail. In situations like this, you typically break inheritance on each %username% folder and replace the permissions that would be inherited from the parent folder with explicit permissions for the user. If you're using redirected folders via GPO, it will automatically do this. If you're manually creating the folders, you'll have to do this by hand or script it. So, they will be able to see that other user folders exist, but they will get an access denied when trying to open them.